# Angular. Binding data from data dictionaries to objects

Tags: javascript, angularjs, data-binding, dictionary

In angular i have few collections. First one is an global 'product attribute' dictionary:

```
attributes : [
    {id:1, value:"red", type:"color"}, 
    {id:2, value:"green", type:"color"}, 
    {id:3, value:"big", type:"size"}
]
```

And i have a 'product' object:

```
cars : [{
    name : "red big car",
    attributes : [1, 3] # id's corresponding to 'attributes' list
}]
```

And now in my template i want to access that data in a easy way:

```
<div ng-repeat='car in cars'>
    <p>{{ car.name }}</p>
    <p ng-repeat='attribute in attributes'>{{ attribute.value }}</p>
</div>
```

To get a result:

```
<div ng-repeat='car in cars'>
    <p>red big car</p>
    <p ng-repeat='attribute in attributes'>red</p>
    <p ng-repeat='attribute in attributes'>big</p>
</div>
```

I know i could iterate through it and copy all that 'attributes' data to 'car' but it would make tons of useless copies of my data. Any other ideas?
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there's no clean mathematical way to compute array indices based on `id`s (like your current example where indexes are (`id`-1)) then I'd create a lookup table that maps array index values to `id`s in the same way  database's often do.  Like so:

```
$scope.lookup = {1:0,
                 2:1,
                 3:2 }
```

Then use that to map the `car` attributes array indexes into array indices into your attributes array:

```
<div ng-repeat='car in cars'>
    <p>{{ car.name }}</p>
   {{car.attributes}}
   <p ng-repeat='indx in car.attributes'>{{attributes[lookup[indx]].value }}</p>
</div>
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RfS4V/2/)

Comment: car.attributes are id's corresponding to 'attributes' list

Comment: I've edited your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RfS4V/3/) based on your ideas i have it almoast working but i dont know if it's a good idea to run it like that.

Comment: The tradeoff of approaches is performance.  The filter in your fiddle definitely works, it's just faster to use a lookup table.  So it's really a question of how much data you have, how big the tables will be and how important performance is.

Comment: My concern is if _.findWhere in an Angular filter is a good idea.

Comment: It's fine other than the performance hit since it'll be called on each $digest cycle.  If your tables aren't very big then either solution should be fine.  If you have performance concerns then there's the lookup approach